# How to change Print Settings to `Print Active Sheets` at run time instead of Print Selection?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to change Print Settings to `Print Active Sheets` instead of Print Selection.
I tried using macro recorder, but it did not capture any code.
Also, this simple vba code just print the active sheet, but it does not change print settings as required at run time.

```
ActiveSheet.PrintOut
```

In advance, your help is appreciated.
[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52426657/vba-in-excel-2016-set-printer-settings-in-code

Comment: @braX I already using code on your provided comment, But it doesn't change settings to `Print Active Sheets` at run-time and I have to close the workbook and open again to take effect.

Comment: See the 2nd example here: [**`Application.ActiveSheet` property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.activesheet).  Also possibly relevant: the [`PageSetup` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup).  (Incidentally I found both with a Google search for: "[print active sheets vba site:microsoft.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=print+active+sheets+vba+site%3Amicrosoft.com)" ...note the last part, which limits it to official documentation.)

Comment: @ashleedawg there's no problem to print active sheet using VBA , all I need is to `change the setting itself` as above photos without close the workbook and open again.

Comment: I am not sure I correctly understand what you really want. Do you need **printing active sheets** (even if more such sheets are selected), or you need to **change the mentioned `PageSetup` setting**, in a way to remain for the next printing?

Comment: @FaneDuru ,All I need is to `change the Setting itself` as on my second Picture.
I think it can only be done by using `PowerShell script` (and this will not on my work).
May be I was wrong when I tagged this question `VBA`.
Kindly advice before I delete this question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

1. The setting in discussion is **workbook specific**. You cannot change it globally even using another language, because of the previous mentioned truth. I mean, using a specific language method.
2. But you can do it, using VBA, simple running a piece of code like the following one printing two sheets. Next time, **for that specific workbook** the setting will be changed. You obtain what you need when the code runs and also change the setting:

```
Sub printActiveSheets()
   Dim wb As Workbook
   
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

   Sheets(Array(wb.Sheets(1).name, wb.Sheets(2).name)).PrintOut
End Sub
```

It will print first and second sheet and will also make the change you need.

In order to check that, please manually print a selection, then look at that specific setting. It will be changed in 'Print Selection`. Then, run the above code and make the same check. You will see 'Print Active Sheets'. It will also be memorized for that specific workbook if you save it.

It is not easy to change that setting, let us say, `As Default`, being valid for all open workbooks. I cannot swear that it is impossible. If I will take it like a challenge I will maybe find some Registry keys able to be handled (as Excel does) in order to do it for all involved workbooks. But the effort cannot be covered by the result, I think. This is the way Excel works, should be the essence of the answer, I also think.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I followed your steps exactly as you mentioned.I don't know is it realted to IT restrictions or not.any way thanks for your effort.

Comment: @user145212 Nothing should be related to IT restrictions... What **does not work*? What does that mean? Do you receive an error? Didn't the above code do what I explained it should? What do you want saying?

Comment: It means `no change for print setting` it is still on **Print Selection**.no error raised.
If I closed the workbook and open , it automatically reset to print Active Sheets ,
But this done with all workbooks even without VBA.

Comment: Did the code print first two sheets? Did you check that specific setting after that? Wasn't it changed?  If changed, did you save the workbook before closing it?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply (my PC has no internet connection).yes I followed your steps exactly as you mentioned , code print first two sheets without problem.In fact I need to ask another important question (not realted to print settings at all)

Comment: @user145212 But you **asked** this question and I would like to understand what happens. "Did you check that specific setting after that?" " If changed, did you save the workbook before closing it?". Then, what 'important question' do you need asking and not simple ask?

Comment: Yes , I fully checked and even saved before check that settings.sorry for misunderstanding about the word **Another** , but another means `additional.`

Comment: @user145212. OK. Then, ask the additional question

Comment: Kindly, when you have free time, could you help with unique answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70737749/match-copy-paste-and-clear-takes-a-long-time-how-to-speed-up