# Match, Copy, Paste and clear takes a long time. How to speed up?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code in one workbook as the following:
(1) Match a range on `SheetA` against a range on `SheetB`.
(2) If the data found on `SheetB,` then some values will be inserted on `SheetB` and `Sheet Log`.
(3) The matched data (rows) on SheetB will be copied to `Sheet Result` and Autofit.
(4) The matched data (rows) on SheetB will be `cleared.` (cut & paste is not applicable).
The count of values on the first range in SheetA is normally 7 or 8 and this macro was as fast as it takes 2 seconds to finish all that steps.
I tried to put 146 values on the first range, but the macro turned to be very slow and it took 35 seconds to finish.
Please, how to speed up and optimize this macro?
**Note:** there is no problem at all to change match code or copy, paste, autofit and clear code.
**Link** for the full macro and sheet on the first comment.

```
Sub Match_Copy()
    With Application
       .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       .ScreenUpdating = False
       .EnableEvents = False
    End With
'----------------------------- Match, Code
     Dim Cell As Object, Match_A As Variant
      For Each Cell In WorkOrder
          Match_A = Application.Match(Cell.value, Auto_Data, 0)
            If Not IsError(Match_A) Then
              
              Cell.Offset(, 6).Resize(1, 3).value = Array("Close", Now, ws.name) 'Put Data of Close in every Area
            
            If ws.name = "SheetB" Then 'Put Data of Close in Log Sheet
              Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3).value = _
              Array(Application.UserName, Now, Cell)
            End If
           End If
        Next Cell

'----------------------------- Copy, Paste, AutoFit and Clear Code
    Dim StatusColumn As Range
    Set StatusColumn = ws.Range("G2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
    
      For Each Cell In StatusColumn
         If Cell.value = "Close" Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Copy
            
            Dim DestRng As Range
              Set DestRng = Sheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                  DestRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

                DestRng.Rows.AutoFit
             If DestRng.Rows.RowHeight < 45 Then DestRng.Rows.RowHeight = 45
                                
            End If
       Next Cell
       
 For Each Cell In StatusColumn
   If Cell.value = "Close" Then
      Cell.EntireRow.Clear
     End If
    Next Cell
'-----------------------------
    With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End sub
```

Comment: Link for the real file https://easyupload.io/rlmnfd

Comment: I used to leave macros running overnight (60MHz was the work computer standard…).

Comment: Running the file with the 146 numbers, taked me 2,5s on my laptop. With 1,000 entries I got about 16 seconds. Is there a point to `For Each ws In Sheets(Array("SheetB"))` and `If ws.name = "SheetB" Then` Shouldn't we just set `ws` to **SheetB**? Not that it helps with speed.

Comment: @Christofer Weber I add for each to loop with another sheets in same workbook , for simplicity I did not add to the above code.

Comment: In **Match, Code** you seem to compare every entry of **SheetB** with `Auto_Data`. Wouldn't Auto data always be shorter, therefore fewer steps to Match each entry of `Auto_Data` with **SheetB** instead?

Comment: @Christofer Weber as I mentioned my question , When Auto_Data is only 7 values , the macro was so fast.But It happened that I had to put 146 values on it.

Comment: Yes, But that's because 99% of time consumed isn't in there, but in **Copy, Paste, AutoFit and Clear Code** Which does one extra copy paste per number added. Without that part, the code runs all 4500+ entries in one second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check the next adapted code. It uses arrays for faster iteration and for faster results return. Also, setting the row height for each cell consumes Excel resources. I commented some rows but no time now for everything. If something unclear, please do  not hesitate to ask for clarifications:

```
Sub Run_Close()
  Dim dStart As Double: dStart = Timer
    
    With Application
       .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
       .ScreenUpdating = False
       .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    '------------------
    Dim lastR As Long: lastR = Sheets("SheetA").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim Auto_Data As Range: Set Auto_Data = Sheets("SheetA").Range("A2:A" & lastR)
    
    Dim Count_Auto_Data As Long: Count_Auto_Data = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Auto_Data)
     If Count_Auto_Data = 0 Then Exit Sub
     
     With Auto_Data
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
     End With
    '------------------
    Sheets("Result").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arrWsFin, arrLog, k As Long
    For Each ws In Sheets(Array("SheetB")) 'There are another 3 Sheets
       ws.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
         
        Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      
        Dim WorkOrder As Range: Set WorkOrder = ws.Range("A3:A" & LastRow)
        Dim arrWO: arrWO = WorkOrder.Value2        'place the range in an array for faster iteration
         ReDim arrWsFin(1 To LastRow, 1 To 3)      'redim array to keep the modifications in ws sheet
         ReDim arrLog(1 To 3, 1 To LastRow): k = 1 'redim array to keep maximum modif of ws sheet
        '----------------------------- Match, Code
         Dim Cell As Object, Match_A As Variant, i As Long
          For i = 1 To UBound(arrWO)
              Match_A = Application.Match(arrWO(i, 1), Auto_Data, 0)
              If Not IsError(Match_A) Then
                   arrWsFin(i, 1) = "Close": arrWsFin(i, 2) = Now: arrWsFin(i, 3) = ws.name
                
                    If ws.name = "SheetB" Then 'Put Data of Close in the array for further return at once
                      arrLog(1, k) = Application.UserName: arrLog(2, k) = Now: arrLog(3, k) = arrWO(i, 1): k = k + 1
                    End If
               End If
          Next i
          ws.Range("G2").Resize(UBound(arrWsFin), UBound(arrWsFin, 2)).Value = arrWsFin
          If k > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrLog(1 To 3, 1 To k - 1)
            Sheets("Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arrLog, 2), UBound(arrLog)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrLog)
          End If
    
         '----------------------------- Copy, Paste and AutoFit, Code
        Dim StatusColumn As Range, totRng As Range, lastCol As Long, arrSt, arrResult, arrRow, j As Long
        lastR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
        Set StatusColumn = ws.Range("G2", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp))
        arrSt = StatusColumn.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
        lastCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set totRng = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(lastR, lastCol))  'total range to extract the row slice
       
        Dim rngClearCont As Range
        ReDim arrResult(1 To lastCol, 1 To lastR): k = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(arrSt)
             If arrSt(i, 1) = "Close" Then
                arrRow = totRng.Rows(i).Value
                'load arrResult array:
                For j = 1 To lastCol
                    arrResult(j, k) = arrRow(1, j)
                Next
                k = k + 1
                If rngClearCont Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngClearCont = StatusColumn.Cells(i) 'set the range necessary to clear rows at the end
                Else
                    Set rngClearCont = Union(rngClearCont, StatusColumn.Cells(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If k > 1 Then
            ReDim Preserve arrResult(1 To lastCol, 1 To k - 1)
            With Sheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(arrResult, 2), _
                                                UBound(arrResult))
                    .Value = Application.Transpose(arrResult)
                    .Rows.RowHeight = 45
            End With
            rngClearCont.EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
        '-----------------------------
Next ws

    With Application
      .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .EnableEvents = True
    End With
  
    MsgBox "Time taken: " & Format(Timer - dStart, "0.00s")  
End Sub
```

It should take less than a second...

Comment: user145212 You can download the updated workbook from [here](https://easyupload.io/37zi4l).

Comment: Excellent , it works and very fast even with big ranges.kindly can you add for your code at end a part to **clear the matched data from sheetB** as delete is not applicable.

Comment: user145212 Not sure I understand what you mean... Do you mean to clear contents of columns "G:I"? If not, please better specify what you need.

Comment: @user145212 Do you mean to also clear the 'PM' values in column A:A? If only the brought data (by the code), shouldn't it mean range "G:I"? I am still not sure that I got you...

Comment: @user145212 So, the answer is the one I suggested: To clear columns "G:I" for the added data. Why this way of saying is not correct? Don't you speak about about these columns when say "containing the matched values"? I do not care too much about any protection, if it lets the code clearing range contents. I only **must** understand what is to be cleared... Can wer start talking in terms or ranges, columns, rows...?

Comment: @user145212 I would only like to emphasize that it is good to try harder to make you understood...:)

Comment: @user145212 I added a line at the end. Please, check the updated code and say if it is what you want. If not, it is easy to be commented/deleted.

Comment: No it does not do my I mean. I need at end of code to search for string **Close** on column G
@ SheetB ,If found then **Clear EntireRowS** contains that word `close`. I already use normal `For Each Loop` to do that ,as you know it iterates slowly .
If array can do that on one shot. That I mean from beginning.

Comment: @user145212 I asked you in clear: "**Do you mean to also clear the 'PM' values in column A:A?**". What did you answer? Is it something I missed? Are there other data than the ones in the testing workbook which must be cleared?

Comment: No, just as my last comment, in advance Great thanks for your patience and efforts.

Comment: @user145212 Do you understand what does **`EntireRow`** mean? "**Are there other data than the ones in the testing workbook which must be cleared?**"

Comment: That is what I tried to describe yesterday, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70751397/faster-method-to-clear-range-of-rows-on-condition-other-than-using-autofilter-or

Comment: @user145212 updated the above code with proposed solution, in order to avoid an extra iteration. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Excellent again, It takes 0.35 seconds to finish all tasks.
Really I admire your mastering of using array with many of your answers.

Answer (score 1):

The root of your issue is that you are making many edits to the worksheet.  One of the first ways to speed up VBA code is to reduce the number of times you write data to the sheet.

Rather than writing your data to the sheet every time in a `For Each` loop, add all of your data to an `Array` and then write that entire `Array` to the sheet(s) at once.  This way, you don't have to write multiple times for every `For Each` loop, but only once.

I cannot guarantee that this is the only reason your code is "sub-optimal" but it's a good place to start to improve performance times.

Comment: @user145212 - It seems like a reasonable answer. It'd be improved, though, if the actual code to write the entire `Array` was shown.

Answer (score 1):

While writing to the sheet does take time, the main problem here is the copy/paste part.

If you, after the row

```
Cell.Offset(, 6).Resize(1, 3).value = Array("Close", Now, ws.name) 'Put Data of Close in every Area
```

Put something like:

```
Sheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 9).value = Array(Cell, , , , , , "Close", Now, ws.name)
```

And then remove the copy/paste part completely, you should be able to run it almost instantly.

Comment: First many thanks, Copy by using direct assignment is wonderful (less coding change), and also speedy.But when comparing with the other answer by "FaneDure", his answer is more fast especially with big ranges (thousands of Rows)

Comment: I am afraid to say, after I tried your code again, it is not working.
It is only copy some values on sheet `Result`.
The expected result is to copy the `entire row` or at least copy cells from `column_A to column_P`.

Comment: Well it's not copying anything, just replicating the circumstances of the example. I didn't want to go the route of Fane and rewrite the entire thing, because I'm not sure exactly what your normal conditions are. So I guess it's more of a "proof of concept" that the copy/paste part is the time-sink. You'll need to modify it to meet your needs, if your needs differ from the example.